# Divide data in to chunks with multiple values in each chunk in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with observations from three years time, with column `df$week` that indicates the week of the observation. (The week count of the second year continues from the count of the first, so the data contains 207 weeks).

I would like to divide the data to longer time periods, to `df$period` that would include all observations from several weeks' time.

If a period would be the length of three weeks, and I the data would include 13 observations in six weeks time, the I idea would be to divide

```
weeks <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
```

into

```
periods <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), c(4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
periods
[1]
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 
[2]
4 5 5 6 6 6
```

To look something like

```
> df
   week period
1     1      1
2     1      1
3     1      1
4     2      1
5     2      1
6     3      1
7     3      1
8     4      2
9     5      2
10    5      2
11    6      2
12    6      2
13    6      2
>
```

The data contains +13k rows so would need to do some sort of map in style of

```
mapPeriod <- function(df, fun) {
  out <- vector("vector_of_weeks", length(df))
  for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    out[i] <- fun(df[[i]])
  }
  out
}
```

I just don't know what to include in the `fun` to divide the weeks to the decided sequences of periods. Can function `rep` be of assistance here? How?

I would be very grateful for all input and suggestions.

Comment: Base R `cut` or `dplyr::ntile` should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
split(weeks, f = (weeks - 1) %/% 3)

$`0`
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

$`1`
[1] 4 5 5 6 6 6
```

**from comments below**

```
weeks <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)

df <- data.frame(weeks)
library(data.table)
df$period <-  data.table::rleid((weeks - 1) %/% 3)
#    weeks  period
# 1      1       1
# 2      1       1
# 3      1       1
# 4      2       1
# 5      2       1
# 6      3       1
# 7      3       1
# 8      4       2
# 9      5       2
# 10     5       2
# 11     6       2
# 12     6       2
# 13     6       2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How could I assign the period numbers `0` and `1`to my data frame? When I try to `df$period <- split(df$week, f = (df$week - 1) %/% 3)` it gives the error `` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, `period, value = list(`0` = c(1, 1,  : replacement has 69 rows, data has 13199 ``